# Editing breadcrumb for product tag archive pages only in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs, custom-taxonomy

I have found where in WooCommerce (WC) I can edit directly to get my desired result, which is editing the following function: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-breadcrumb.php#L222

```
private function add_crumbs_product_tag() {
        $current_term = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get_queried_object();
        $this->prepend_shop_page();
        /* translators: %s: product tag */
        $this->add_crumb( sprintf( __( 'My Edit: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $current_term->name ), get_term_link( $current_term, 'product_tag' ) );
    }
```

Now I know that it is bad practice to directly edit the WC plugin, so I am looking for an alternative, so that when WC updates, the changes aren't overwritten.

**Override Attempt**

I have tried to add my edited class to my child theme (mytheme-child/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-breadcrumb.php) but this doesn't seem to work.

What can I do?

Comment: Hey I would really recommend this documentation: https://iandunn.name/2014/01/10/the-right-way-to-customize-a-wordpress-plugin/
Anyhow I would do it with hooks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead using the specific `woocommerce_get_breadcrumb` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_product_tag_crumb', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_tag_crumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    // Targetting product tags
    $current_taxonomy  = 'product_tag';
    $current_term      = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get_queried_object();
    $current_key_index = sizeof($crumbs) - 1;

    // Only product tags
    if( is_a($current_term, 'WP_Term') && term_exists( $current_term->term_id, $current_taxonomy ) ) {
        // The label term name
        $crumbs[$current_key_index][0] = sprintf( __( 'My Edit: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $current_term->name );
        // The term link (not really necessary as we are already on the page)
        $crumbs[$current_key_index][1] = get_term_link( $current_term, $current_taxonomy );
    }
    return $crumbs;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.